# Open terminal via AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applications, applescript, shortcut

I'm tring to write a shortcut script in spark for opening the terminal.

```
on run {input, parameters}

  tell application "Utilities/Terminal" // tried Utilities:Terminal and Terminal too
    reopen
    activate
  end tell

end run
```

how can make this work? I'm using 10.10.2 as OSX version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the correct method:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    -- insert your code here
end tell
```

EDIT
You can open new windows with do script

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
end tell
```

Comment: this is a better solution. can you check my comment on Matthiue's answer.

Comment: Do you want 1 terminal window or a new window for every time you run the command?

Comment: I want more windows. I want to be able to pass them with cmd` shortcut

Comment: This seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
tell application "Terminal"
   activate
  tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}
end tell
```

Should do the job.

Comment: I want it to open multiple times so I tried to put reopen(didnt work) then wrote this: do shell script "open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app" but the problem is I can't switch tabs with cmd`(below esc) button