# How to run a command on open terminal via shortcut

Tags: terminal, shortcut

I am developing using electron on macOS. After making changes we need to run the terminal command `npm start` to run the app.

I would like to create a shortcut on macOS so that it simply switches focus on the terminal and runs the command.

Currently I'm using this, but it loads a new terminal window:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        reopen
        activate
        do script "npm start"
    end tell

end run
```

I can't initiate a new terminal for this as the command has to be run from the current project folder to start it.

Any help in right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23975628/4381356 - 'do script' will open a new window anyway. Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/170604/85275

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer to this query so wanted to share.

The problem with the code in question was that it was opening the new temrinal window.

The solution was th prevent it from doing that by running the code in already open window, by mentioning the `window 1` in it like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "npm start" in window 1
end tell
```

We can also use `keycode` and `keystroke` technique discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1870270/953566 too, however that was too lengthy and complicated, but can be useful in someones situation.